# It works, but is it right?

Tags: c++, cout

Do I fill object fields with the help of methods in a dynamic array of objects.It works, but is it right?

```
EXAM* Array = new EXAM[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Please type a name of the student: ";
        cin>>naMe;
        Array[i].setName(naMe);//Is it OK to access an object method this way in case of dynamic allocation?
        cout<<endl<<"Please type the date of exam: ";
        cin>>daTe;
        Array[i].setDate(daTe);
        cout<<"Please type mark: ";
        cin>>maRk;
        Array[i].setMark(maRk); 
    }
```

Comment: Right is subject.  IMHO it is not right as you should be using a `std::vector` instead of having a naked `new` but that is subjective.

Comment: Probably better on __Code Review Stack Exchange__: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `std::vector<EXAM>` will take care of your array needs

Comment: Did you try creating a list? That would be more effective I think
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41525/creating-objects-and-putting-them-into-stdlist

Comment: @RichardCritten It would still be off topic there, it's not clear what the OP means by *"right"*.

Comment: @SQLserving, The general consensus is to default to `std::vector`. In many cases, `std::list` ends up being premature pessimization, not to mention lower-tier iterators.

Comment: @SQLserving using std::list is an exercise in slowing down code.

Comment: OP just worries that he uses '.' on dynamically allocated object

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I agree and already have flagged to close as "opinion based"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, following constructions are equivalent:

```
pointer[i].method();
(pointer + i)->method();
(*(pointer + i )).method();
```

Similar to this:

```
object.method();
(&object)->method();
(*(&object)).method();
```

That just different syntax to express the same thing. It does not matter were pointer came from, ie if it points to dynamically allocated memory, local or global object. Syntax working with pointers and arrays stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it is not right??

If mark and date are also strings (or are converted in the setDate and setMark functions) this looks like ok code!